# HackerRank Array Manipulation Solution in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures

Can anyone help me where I am wrong in my code? Because I am unable to pass all the test cases.

I have to optimize this program so that it can be executed in less time can you help??

this program is supposed to initialize an array of a size n(function argument) with 0(lets call array arr) then there will be query in form

```
a b k
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

and then in array arr we have add k between the limits a and b and then return max of arr

```
example Sample Input

5 3
1 2 100
2 5 100
3 4 100

Sample Output

200

Explanation

After the first update list will be 100 100 0 0 0.
After the second update list will be 100 200 100 100 100.
After the third update list will be 100 200 200 200 100.
The returned answer will be 200.
```

Here is my code

```
        var sum = 0;
        var greatestInteger = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }

        for(int k = 0; k <= queries.GetUpperBound(0); k++)
        {
            arr[queries[k][0]- 1] += queries[k][2];
            arr[queries[k][1]] -= queries[k][2];  
        }
        greatestInteger = arr[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += arr[i];
            if(sum > greatestInteger)
            {
                greatestInteger = sum;
            }
        }
        return greatestInteger;
```

Comment: What are you attempting to do?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays  - Click on this link for the question @johnnyMopp

Comment: Nope, you get to tell what you are trying to do, and what you think is going on. Do you get any feedback (like the algorithm you are using is too slow with large datasets)? If so, tell us that too

Answer (score 2):

The above codes are fine but lack many aspects I don't know if they have tested it or not. Here is the proper code in c#:

```cs
static long arrayManipulation(int n, int[][] queries) {
    long[] computation = new long[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < queries.Length; i++) {
        int a = queries[i][0] - 1;
        int b = queries[i][1] - 1;
        int k = queries[i][2];

        computation[a] += k;
        if (b + 1 < n ) {
            computation[b + 1] -= k;
        }
    }

    long max = 0; long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += computation[i];
        max = Math.Max(max, sum);
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
private long FindGreatestNumber(int arraySize, int[,] queries)
        {
            long max = 0;
            var array = new long[arraySize];
            for (int i = 0; i < queries.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                int start = queries[i, 0] - 1;
                int end = queries[i, 1] - 1;
                for (int j = start; j <= end; j++)
                {
                    array[j] += queries[i, queries.GetLength(1) - 1];
                    if (array[j] > max)
                        max = array[j];
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
```

I believe if you use an integer array it will overflow.

Comment: If you want to do this challenge, maybe consider going and doing it yourself on hackerrank, not "doing someone's homework for them"

Comment: @CaiusJard you could argue that for a great number of posts here. Not everybody is at the same level. You can actually learn by analyzing solutions to problems you cannot figure out yourself. I do leetcode every now and then, and that's enough for me.

Comment: I will forever promote that teaching a person how to fish holds more value than giving a person a fish. I couldn't care less that "a great number of posts here" are donations of fish seeking fake internet points in return; I care greatly about raising the quality of software engineering by actively being involved in a solution process rather than being an answering machine (and I do reserve the right to harp on at folks that post a code only answer with zero explanation or attempts at education)

Comment: I don't think the question is useless (despite multiple other people thinking thus) because I posted an answer, but I think the notion of taking on a personal challenge for your own benefit and then coming and asking the SO community to solve it for you is wrong for all kinds of reasons, which is why I didn't just out and out give you the answer but spent a reasonable amount of time giving as many pointers as I could to aid your learning and get you to solve this challenge yourself. It's also why I'm pointing out to insane_developer that just giving you the answer does everyone a disservice

Comment: If I would not have mentioned the word "hacker rank", I guess this won't be happening and everyone would be taking this as a serious question to figure out the problem i actually have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really believe in the notion of "I'm going to do this web challenge to prove what an awesome coder I am. Hmm. I couldn't complete the challenge. I'm going to ask someone on SO to do it for me" because it's all kinds of wrong, from plagiarism to misrepresenting yourself in an interview to getting fired because you couldn't do the job you were hired for, potentially with dire consequences (if you're writing eg aircraft control software)..

..but I'm prepared to fill in on your existing solution some comments that I imagine could reasonably go above the code in question, and I hope they will help you figure out how it might not meet the challenge

```
    //skip the part where I declare the array and the number of queries according to the first line of the input 

    //declare some variables far away from where they will be used, just for extra fun 
    var sum = 0;
    var greatestInteger = 0;

    //init arr to all zeroes, in case c# forgot to take its default action of doing that
    for(int i = 0; i< arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }

    //queries is just the lines of manipulation instructions; the first line of input
    //was magically dispensed with somewhere else 
    //use a variable called k as an indexer, even though the challenge uses a variable called k to mean something else 
    //just to add in some extra confusion factor for anyone looking at this code 
    for(int k = 0; k <= queries.GetUpperBound(0); k++)
    {
        //the challenge wants every array element between two inclusive 1-based indexes to be incremented
        //and c# uses 0base indexes so I'll sub one off the start index to keep it in line
        //increment the arr start index a by k (the challenge's k, not my variable k)
        arr[queries[k][0]- 1] += queries[k][2];

        //skip the part where I'm supposed to increment everything between a and b by k

        //drop that 0base/1base adjustment logic we did earlier and instead of incrementing, 
        //decrement the arr that is one after the end index by k instead
        arr[queries[k][1]] -= queries[k][2];  
    }

    //forgot to keep a track of the biggest int while we were making
    //the manipulations so we'll do another scan of the array to
    //find it now. Init greatestinteger to be the first element of the array so we could save a loop cycle by starting he loop from 1
    greatestInteger = arr[0];

    //loop over the array, starting from 0
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        //accumulate the current array element onto a running total of all the array elements
        sum += arr[i];

        //if the running total is bigger than the biggest integer so far
        if(sum > greatestInteger)
        {
            //then set the biggest bit to be equal to the running total
            greatestInteger = sum;
        }
    }
    //return the total sum of all the array elements, essentially
    return greatestInteger;
```

Ultimately here I've done the exact opposite of what you *should* have done when you sat down to tackle this challenge. You ought to have written the algorithm out in comments *first* and then written the c# underneath it. You'd have ended up with nicely commented code that implemented the algorithm. Instead you've written code that *doesn't* implement the algorithm because you've tried to hold it all in your head and write it out, you've generated incorrect code and not met the spec - clear omissions like factoring the off-by-one on one line then forgetting it on the next indicate to me that *you weren't working to a high level plan that would keep you on track*. I have reverse commented in that I've taken the incorrect code you've written and turned it into a comment, hopefully in a way that makes it blatantly obvious where it differs from the challenge.

I'd recommend starting over, write the algorithm in comments first, then write C#.

All pro devs write algorithms and complicated designs out in high level language and abstractions first; its the hallmark of a good software engineer, not a bad one

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stupid solution

```
    public static long arrayManipulation(int n, List<List<int>> queries)
    {
        List<long> myList = new List<long>(new long[n]);

        foreach (var list in queries)
        {
            for (int i = list[0] - 1; i <= list[1] - 1; ++i)
            {
                myList[i] += list[2];
            }
        }

        return myList.Max();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static long arrayManipulation(int n, List<List<int>> queries)
    {
            long[]  outputArray= new long[n];
                for (int i = 0; i < queries.Count(); i++) {
                   outputArray[queries[i][0]-1]=outputArray[queries[i][0]-1] +queries[i][2];
                   if(queries[i][1]<n)
                   {
                   outputArray[queries[i][1]]=outputArray[queries[i][1]]- queries[i][2];   
                   }
                }
                long temp=0,max=0;
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                    temp=temp+outputArray[i];
                    if(temp>max)
                        max=temp;
                }
                 return max;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this challenge is that many viable solutions timeout the service.    I put all the indexes into a distinct array then used linq to select the sum of k's where each index was between a and b inclusive then take the max and it timed out on several tests.  I see one solution here that used arrays in memory that doesn't time out, that's cool and all until you do a problem like this for a job interview and it times out on a viable solution that reflects different coding expertise (my solution does not evaluate irrelevant columns because I realized columns that do not include any a or b can not be a max and that was where I tried to optimize it when it first timed out).